# Finding a formula with given values

Tags: functions

I am trying to construct the formula for a falling player in Minecraft (a game).

I have tested in the game and found the following;
If I jump and fall 125 blocks, I will have traveled around 20 blocks horizontally.
If I jump and fall 50 blocks, I will have traveled around 11 blocks horizontally.
and so on...

Summed up, I have three points
(20, 125) and (11, 50) and (16, 88)

how do I find the corresponding formula for this?

Comment: You have to guess some set of dependencies for $(l,h)$. Say, we search the answer in form $(l,al^2+bl)$, then $400a+20b=125, 121a+11b=50$ and you can find specific $a$ and $b$.

Comment: These data are not enough to compute a formula. You must give us another jump.

Comment: There are tons of functions fitting your query. A simple class is made of the affine functions $$f(x)=ax+b.$$ To look for $f$ in this class, solve the system $$20a+b=125\qquad 11a+b=50$$ which yields in your case $$f(x)=\frac{25}3(x-5).$$ Adding a third point (for example, $(0,0)$) will in general force you to look for *quadratics* $$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c,$$ and so on with polynomial functions of degree $n$ to fit $n+1$ points.

Comment: @Crostul It stands to reason that we have $(0,0)$ as well. Then again, for any $n$ points there is a polynomial of degree $n-1$...

Comment: @Did Yes, but there is also measurement error (in Minecraft case, values are *somehow* rounded to integer). In physics, you get some points, look at them and try to guess the general kind of a curve. Then compute specific coefficients, add some new points and look how well your formula predicted results. That's it, more or less.

Comment: @Abstraction Is this comment supposed to address something I wrote?

Comment: @Did Yes, that last sentence about polynomials of degree $n$ for $n+1$ points - this is good only to perfectly get your *past* results; in practice, with many points this approach is worse than, say, spline interpolation - both in computation complexity and prediction precision.

Comment: @Abstraction OK. Sure these considerations enter what the OP is asking?

Comment: @Did Thanks! I can now calculate whether my players are using Glide cheats. That means that they fall like a feather, and can travel much further than without cheating. I now calculate and compare how much they fall and move. The formula didn't have to be specific as I rounded everything up. This way the final  formula can only give the cheaters a slight advantage, which also prevents tiny lag to mess up.

Comment: @Did Well, in OP case $h(l)$ is quadratic, maybe with some random noise added ($h(t)={gt^2 \over 2}+v_0t\cos(\alpha), l(t)=v_0t\sin(\alpha)$). But just saying that doesn't answer general case "how to find formula extrapolating these measurements".

Comment: @Abstraction You are again adding to the OP's question some ingredients that you deem important and which may well be but *which are not there*.

Comment: @Did Well, yes, you're right. I see the question and I *think* I understand what task OP tries to solve, but it wasn't stated directly. But precise answer for the task "(re)construct the formula by finite number of values" is "it's impossible unless something else is known about the formula".

Answer (score 0):

by using the Lagrange interpolating formula (Three points)
$$y=L_0y_0+L_1y_1+L_2y_2$$
$$L_0=\frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)}{(x_0-x_1)(x_0-x_2)}=\frac{(x-11)(x-16)}{(20-11)(20-16)}$$
$$L_1=\frac{(x-x_0)(x-x_2)}{(x_1-x_0)(x_1-x_2)}=\frac{(x-20)(x-16)}{(11-20)(11-16)}$$
$$L_2=\frac{(x-x_0)(x-x_1)}{(x_2-x_0)(x_2-x_1)}=\frac{(x-20)(x-11)}{(16-20)(16-11)}$$